Problem to insert bibliography in "Template for submissions to Scientific Reports" / Overleaf
Setup: Downloaded "Template for submissions to Scientific Reports" from Springer website.
Opened in with the Overleaf.
Problem: Cannot understand how to generate references list.
When compile the template - there is no section "Referenes/Bibliography", despite
there is file "sn-bibliography.bib" and there is command "\bibliography{sn-bibliography}" in the main file.
Question: Any advises to resolve problem  ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you need to \cite some entry in the .bib file then you need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex then pdflatex again to generate and include the bibliography

@DavidCarlisle can you clarify please , what does it mean "then bibtex" ? Usually I just press "complie" in overleaf and it works

ah overleaf will run the required sequence for you unless an error means it can not get to the end. do you have a \cite in your document and do you have any error marked with a red error count at the top of the pdf view?

@DavidCarlisle Yes there are "\cite"(s) and they appear in pdf as "[?]". The red error is : "I couldn't open style file sn-mathphys-num.bst : \bibstyle{sn-mathphys-num : }" Despite there is such file in \bst subfolder of the TEX project .

why didn't you put that information in the question? bibtex will not find the bst file in a bst directory, place it in the main directory or use \bibliographystyle{bst/sn-mathphys-num}  how come there is a : in the error message you show? You need to give people at least some hint of what you have done if you want help.
